# Unique autogenerated ID for differet django models

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

I have 3 model classes that inherit from a parent abstract class, like so:

```
      class ParentClass(models.Model):
          class Meta:
              abstract = True

      class ChildClass1(ParentClass):
          ...


      class ChildClass2(ParentClass):
          ...


      class ChildClass3(ParentClass):
          ...
```

I was wondering if there was a way to let Django generate id's as usual, but making sure that no instances of either `ChildClass1`, `ChildClass2`, or `ChildClass3` will have overlapping id's. So for example the following code:

```
    a = ChildClass1.objects.create()
    b = ChildClass2.objects.create()
    c = ChildClass3.objects.create()
    print(a.pk)
    print(b.pk)
    print(c.pk)
```

shuld return:

```
    1
    2
    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an id equal to the current number of objects in the db.  Something like:

```
class ParentClass(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    abstract = True

  @classmethod
  def get_next_id(cls):
    n_children = ChildClass1.objects.count() + ChildClass2.objects.count() + ChildClass3.objects.count()
    return n_children + 1

class ChildClass1(ParentClass):
  my_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=ParentClass.get_next_id, primary_key=True)
   ...
```

You may want to make `get_next_id` a bit more clever to automatically check all child classes as with https://stackoverflow.com/a/49295674/1060339

Answer (score 0):

You can get unique primary key for the different model

```
import uuid    
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Comment: Yup, that's cool, but I was wondering if it's possible to have them assigned in an incremental way and automatically like Django does by default with models. Also possibly just integers id's.

Comment: I have a bad solution. Go to your database console and run like this: `alter table tablename auto_increment=1000001`. You can start your first model from 100000, second model from 200000 and so on.

Comment: Not really doable, the application is meant for logs that are frequently generated. Besides the target audience is extremely large